# "Would you like this or no" vs "Would you like this or not"?

Tags: negation

I would like to discern if both of these phrasings are correct and if they possibly even mean different things.  One of them bothers me terribly.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to ask is "Would you like this or would you *not*?"

When you abbreviate that, it becomes "Would you like this or not?"
The other sentence, though grammatically incorrect, is accepted informally. It implies the same thing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd even go so far as to say "or no" might be MORE accepted informally in some cases. "Would you like this or not" is often used rhetorically under the assumption that they DO want it, so it's possible for it come off as rude.

Comment: Grammatically though, saying "or no" is incorrect. If you expand the question, "or no" will not fit. Having said that, I do completely agree with @the-baby-is-you that "or no" is acceptable informally.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how you expand it? Arguably, the structure is actually that of "Yes or no?", wherein the "Yes" option is replaced by something more specific. "Would you like this?" "I would like this./No."